# Trying to use androidx's junit-gtest solution

Tags: android, junit, android-ndk, googletest, androidx

I am trying to hook up my native tests (written using google's gtest) with android studio and the main instrumented tests framework.

So far I have had no / very limited success.

For example, most of the (very few) documentation resources I found suggest to use cmake's `find_package` function, but it always fails to find it. Instead I have to build gtest from source found in the NDK.

Besides, when trying to run a test with the GTestRunner class it fails because it doesn't find native methods from androidx junit-gtest. These methods are defined in a "a" library file that is part of the `junit-gtest.aar` as provided by androidx, but I can't find a robust way to instruct cmake where to find it.

Has anyone on this list managed to use junit-gtest ? Or has anyone an alternative solution to run native unit tests from within android-studio as part of instrumented tests (that are run on device)

Thanks !

I've had some progress since I posted this question. To be able to use `find_package(junit-gtest REQUIRED CONFIG)` the module's `build.gradle` needs to activate the prefab build feature :

```
...
buildFeatures {
    buildConfig = true
    prefab true
}
...
```

Once this is done, I manage to run the tests, but they don't seem to be reporting correctly to the IDE. Android-studio shows a single test in canceled state (the test's code is as simple as `ASSERT_TRUE(true);`)

I'll post more info here as I progress further.

Comment: Did you look at https://github.com/android/ndk-samples/tree/main/unit-test?